# How to do proofs by induction with 3 variables? (Follow-up question)

Tags: logic, induction

(Follow-up question to [How to do proofs by induction with 2 variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3873041/how-to-do-proofs-by-induction-with-2-variables))

Suppose you want to prove that $P(x,y,z)$ is true for all $x,y,z \in N$. Will it suffice to prove each of  the following?

1. $P(0,0,0)$
2. For all $k \in N:[P(0,0,k) \implies P(0,0, k+1)]$
3. For all $j, k \in N:[P(0,j, k) \implies P(0,j+1, k)]$
4. For all $i,j,k \in N:[P(i,j,k) \implies P(i+1,j ,k)$

**EDIT: This theorem may NOT be all that useful in writing proofs.**

Comment: Yes,... That will do.  Or you could also prove that $P(i,j,k)\implies \begin{cases}P(i,j,k+1)\\P(i,j+1,k)\\ P(i+1,j,k)\end{cases}$.  You don't need so set the subcases to $0$ and you don't have to do the variables right to left.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Think of $\{(i,j,k) | i,j, k \ge 0\}$ as an infinite lattice. Put a drop of black ink on a vertex to indicate the you have established that $P(i,j,k)$ is true.

- Point 1 puts a drop of ink on the origin.
- Point 2 extends that drop along the whole $k$ axis.
- Point 3 takes a squeegee to the $k$ axis and inks up the whole $j$-$k$ plane.
- Point 4 draw the ink up vertically from the $j$-$k$ plane to ink the entire lattice.

More formally, you can think of it as a series of 3 "standard" induction proofs:

- Points 1 and 2 establish $P(0,0,k)$ for all $k$.
- Point 3 establishes $P(0,j,k)$ for all $j$ and $k$, by induction on $j$, where $k$ is a parameter in the statement. You can also think of this as proving an infinite family of statements, $\forall j P(0,j, 0) $,  $\forall j P(0,j, 1)$, $\forall j P(0,j, 2)$, ... etc.. Note that the base case for each of each of these inductions is what you proved in the first induction proof.
- And then Point 4 establishes $P(i,j,k)$ for all $i,j,k$, where you do induction on $i$, and $j$ and $k$ are parameters. You can also think of this case as proving a family of propositions, where this time they are doubly-indexed by $(j,k)$. And again the base case for each of these inductions was proved in the previous induction.

To really beat this into the ground, you could also approach it via [induction on well-ordered sets](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Principle_of_Mathematical_Induction/Well-Ordered_Set), which is more general than the usual induction on $\mathbb N$ that we first learn.

You can consider your set of $(i,j,k)$ as $\mathbb N^3$, and give it the dictionary order. Then the conditions you stated end up being exactly what are needed to find an element less than an arbitrary element of $\mathbb N^3$, with different cases corresponding to the number of leading $0$s in $(i,j,k)$.

I think this view has a nice structure, as the original question seems to come from a worry of "Have I covered all the cases needed?", and you end up "unwrapping" 3 layers of the definition of dictionary order, which corresponds to the fact that you're looking at triples of $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices but is not necessary.

You can also consider

1. $P(0,0,0)$ (Base case)
2. $P(i,j,k)\implies P(i,j,k+1)$ (No need to assume $i,j$ are $0$)
3. $P(i,j,k)\implies P(i,j+1,k)$
4. $P(i,j,k)\implies P(i+1,j,k)$

But you can do it your way.  Hypothetically, there may be a case where proving $P(0,0,k)\implies P(0,0,k+1)$ is easier than for any $P(i,j,k)\implies P(i,j,k+1)$.  In which case you can do it your way.  But you don't have do do the variables in *that* order.  If $P(i,j,k)\implies P(i,j+1,k)$ is hard but the other two are easy, you can always start with $P(0,j,0)\implies P(0,j+1,0)$ first if that makes things easier.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean to write $P(0,i,0)$.

Comment: I most certainly *DID* mean to write $P(0,i,0)$.  If doing the middle vairable is easier with the other being $0$ you *can* do it that way.

Comment: Oh, I would have expected you to write that as $P(0,j,0)$. Everyone's been using $i$ for the first slot and $j$ for the second slot, so $P(i,0,0)$ or $P(0,j,0)$ would have been consistent with that -- that's what confused me. I mean, it's not mathematically wrong to write $P(0,i,0)$ here, but it certainly made me stop and wonder (heck, assume) that there was a typo. Sorry if that was what you intended.

Comment: Oh, well that was just a typo.  I assumed you were asking about the position of the non zero term being in the middle.  But it doesn't matter *what* variables we mean.  So I could have written $P(0, \gamma, 0)$ as far as anyone cares.  There is *no* relation between the $i$ in one expression and the $i$ in any other expression.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I was trying to make a point about clarity of exposition, not correctness. Heck, you could write $P(0, क , 0) \implies P(0, क +1, 0)$ and still be just as correct, but I think following conventions helps people get the point of an argument more easily.